# Security of Keccak/SHA3 against birthday attacks

Tags: sha-3, keccak, birthday-attack

If I understand it correctly the security of $\operatorname{Keccak}$ depends on the capacity $c$, which means that I get a security level of $2^{128}$ for $c=128$ (I omitted the value $r$ here because I think that it is irrelevant to my question...but correct me if I'm wrong).

But in every publication I found (and even on the $\operatorname{Keccak}$ website), it is said that the security does not depend on the output length. I don't understand how the value of $c$ is relevant to birthday attacks. For every single hash function, I can just run a birthday attack regardless of the inner construction of the hash function, right? Which means that for a $\operatorname{Keccak}$ implementation with $c=128$ but an output length of let's say $64$ bits, I can find a collision after $2^{32}$ steps using the birthday paradox, regardless of the value of $c$, right?

Let's even take it one step further. How is Keccak with $c=128$ and an output length of 1 bit still secure? For practical applications, it simply just can't be...

Comment: Of course important security properties depend on the output size. Collision resistance is $\min(c/2,n/2)$ and preimage resistance $\min(c/2,n)$ where $n$ is the output size. On the other hand indistinguishably doesn't depend on the output size. Where did you find something that claimed that the output size doesn't matter for collision/preimage resistance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us correct some of your numbers. The size of the capacity is twice the size of the expected security margin (against a birthday attack). This is the idea of *flat sponge clain* etc

> When using a random sponge as a security reference, one considers the success of a particular attack. Such a success probability depends not only on the nature of the attack considered but also on the chosen parameters of the random sponge, i.e., its capacity, bitrate and whether it calls a random permutation or a random transformation. **The flat sponge claim is a simplification in the sense that we consider only the worst-case success probability, determined by the upper bound on the random oracle differentiating advantage** [Bertoni et al., Eurocrypt'08], which depends solely on the capacity of the random sponge. Hence, it flattens the claimed success probabilities of all attacks using a single parameter: the claimed capacity $c_{\mathit{claim}}$. [[source]](http://sponge.noekeon.org/)

Thus if you aim for a security margin of $128$ bits, you need to have a capacity of $256$ bits.

> In this approach, one designs a permutation $f$ on $b=r+c$ bits and uses it in the sponge construction to build the sponge function $F$. In addition, one makes a flat sponge claim on $F$ with a claimed capacity equal to the capacity used in the sponge construction, namely $c_{\mathit{claim}}=c$. In other words, the claim states that the best attacks on $F$ must be generic attacks. Hence, $c_{\mathit{claim}}=c$ means that any attack on $F$ with expected complexity below $2^{c/2}$ implies a structural distinguisher on $f$, and the design of the permutation therefore attempts to avoid such distinguishers. Note that the existence of a structural distinguisher for $f$ does not necessarily imply an attack or weakness in $F$. For example, any distinguisher for $f$ that has success probability zero below $2^{c/2}$ forms no threat, as the flat sponge claim expresses no security against adversaries that may send more that $2^{c/2}$ queries. [[source]](http://sponge.noekeon.org/)

**TL;DR: the security margin is half the capacity. If you aim for 128 bits, you need a capacity of 256 bits.**

That being said, we can move to your misunderstanding. You are right to say that if you take an output length of $1$ bit, you won't have the $64$ bits security claim... because *you are looking for a collision in the output*.

When you use $\operatorname{Keccak}$, you can retrieve the full size of the bit rate ($r$). You can also extend this output and because these outputs are *related*  (as you basically always know the content of the *bit rate* part). Thus the only part that you don't know is the capacity. If you are able to guess or have a collision on this part, then the output is compromised.

#### The capacity is the only part of the state that you don't know.

When you want a collision, you look either to have a collision on the capacity part or on the bitrate part which is usually bigger than the capacity...

Let $a,b$ be two inputs and $c,c_1,c_2$ the capacity part. You have a collision when :
$$f(a) \to [\theta \mathbin\| c_1]\\f(b) \to [\theta \mathbin\| c_2]$$
where $[\theta \mathbin\| c]$ is full state and $\theta$ is the resulting output (here your output length is important).

The other way to find a collision is to manage to get:
$$f(a) \to [\alpha \mathbin\| c]\\f(b) \to [\beta \mathbin\| c]$$
(collision in the capacity), because then you can have (due to the simplified sponge construction):
$$\begin{align}
f(a \mathbin\| 0) & \to [\alpha \mathbin\| c] &\Rightarrow&&& f([\alpha \oplus 0 \mathbin\| c]) \to \theta \\
f(b \mathbin\| \beta \oplus \alpha) & \to [\beta \mathbin\| c] &\Rightarrow&&& f([\beta \oplus \beta \oplus \alpha \mathbin\| c] ) = f([\alpha \mathbin\| c]) \to \theta
\end{align}$$

TL;DR 2: as @CodeInChaos said **Collision resistance is $\min(c/2,n/2)$ and preimage resistance $\min(c/2,n)$ where n is the output size.**. But most papers search collisions on $\operatorname{Keccak}[1600]$ thus why they usually state this more *generic* security margin ($2^{\mathit{capacity}/2}$).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Now it has become more clear for  me.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but why is the preimage resistance $\min(c/2, n)$ rather than $\min(c, n)$?

Comment: Just for reference, the preimage-attack in $c/2$ is explained here: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/98298/86858